# Python Flask routing - how to get parameter from MethodView class

Tags: python, flask, routes

In my new job we are using the Flask framework (I'm newbie in the Flask). Every view is the child of MethodView. The code looks like this:

```
from flask import render_template
from flask.views import MethodView

class HelloWorldPage(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return render_template('helloworld.html')


def configure_routing(app):
    app.add_url_rule('/<lang>/helloworld', view_func=HelloWorldPage.as_view('helloworld'))
```

Of course, `configure_routing(app)` from `helloworld.py` is called in appropriate place. Now, my question is if it's possible to get `<lang>` from route? When I write `get(self, lang)` it throws an exception `TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`, when I create a method called `helloworld(lang)`, it throws me that method get is not implemented and so on. Thank you very much. Bye

**Edit:**

traceback to `get(self, lang)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 149, in dispatch_request
    return meth(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: The `TypeError` is wrong. It should be `get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lang'`

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry for my reaction @RajaSimon. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: Can you provide the whole trackback?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried the same**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.views import MethodView

app = Flask(__name__)

class HelloWorldPage(MethodView):
        def get(self, lang):
                return render_template('HelloWorld.html', language=lang)

app.add_url_rule('/<lang>/helloworld', view_func=HelloWorldPage.as_view('helloworld'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

**response below**

[image]

comment from flask.views

> METHODVIEW : 
>       Like a regular class-based view but that dispatches requests to
>       particular methods.  For instance if you implement a method called
>       :meth:`get` it means it will respond to `'GET'` requests and
>       the :meth:`dispatch_request` implementation will automatically
>       forward your request to that.  Also :attr:`options` is set for you
>       automatically::

*Did you restrart the service after changing **get(self)** to **get(self, lang)** ?*

if you did then please check the application init file where you import HelloWorldPage view and make sure

```
app = Flask(__name__)

## IMPORT YOUR APP VIEWS 
## THEN CONFIGURE THE ROUTINGS
def configure_routing(app):
    app.add_url_rule('/<lang>/helloworld', view_func=HelloWorldPage.as_view('helloworld'))
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I restarted the service, and I assure myself that everything looks ok - in helloworld.py (it's view), there is a method `configure_routing(app)`, where the routing rule is set. In __init__.py there is a `create_app()` function, where is called `app = Flask(__name__)` and `configure_routing(app)`. In run.py there finally is `app = create_app()` and `if __name__ == '__main__': app.run()`. Looks strange, like I wrote, it's the system in my job, so it's not my work, and maybe there is something what disables this function (but I have no idea). I'll try it on clean project.

Comment: okay, what version of Flask are you using? because see the version0.8 http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/changelog/  ""HEAD requests to a method view now automatically dispatch to the get method if no handler was implemented."""

Comment: Hi again, we use Flask 0.12, but I've finally found the problem. The problem is in language processing. When parameter `<lang>` is in URL, it's catched, stored, cutted off from URL and the system is redirected without `<lang>` parameter (I don't like it, but it is like it is). So when I add another route params as it is usual in Flask, it's possible to get it as parameter in view method. Now, I don't know if I should someway delete my question or something? Could you please give me some instructions what to do with my "wrong" question? Thank you all :-)